# Is log loss in XGBoost and Sklearn the same?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, xgboost

I'm playing around with a new data set with XGBoost. Following is my code:

```
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv("train_users_processed_onehot.csv")
labels = train["Buy"].map({"Y":1, "N":0})

features = train.drop("Buy", axis=1)
data_dmat = xgb.DMatrix(data=features, label=labels)

params={"max_depth":5, "min_child_weight":2, "eta": 0.1, "subsamples":0.9, "colsample_bytree":0.8, "objective" : "binary:logistic", "eval_metric": "logloss", "seed": 2333}
rounds = 6000

result = xgb.cv(params=params, dtrain=data_dmat, num_boost_round=rounds, early_stopping_rounds=50, as_pandas=True, seed=2333)
print result
```

The result is (omitted intermediate results):

```
         test-logloss-mean  test-logloss-std  train-logloss-mean  
0             0.683354          0.000058            0.683206  
165           0.622318          0.000661            0.607680
```

But when I'm trying to do parameter tuning with `GridSearchCV`, I found the result to be quite different. To be more specific, this is my code:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train_dataframe = pd.read_csv("train_users_processed_onehot.csv")
train_labels = train_dataframe["Buy"].map({"Y":1, "N":0})
train_features = train_dataframe.drop("Buy", axis=1)

params = {"max_depth": [5], "min_child_weight": [2]}

estimator = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=170, max_depth=2, min_child_weight=4, objective="binary:logistic", subsample=0.9, colsample_bytree=0.8, seed=2333)

gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid=params, n_jobs=4, iid=False, verbose=1, scoring="neg_log_loss")
gsearch1.fit(train_features.values, train_labels.values)

print pd.DataFrame(gsearch1.cv_results_)
print gsearch1.best_params_
print -gsearch1.best_score_
```

and I got:

```
   mean_fit_time  mean_score_time  mean_test_score  mean_train_score  
0       87.71497         0.209772        -3.134132         -0.567306
```

It is clear that 3.134132 is very different from 0.622318. What's the reason of this?

Thank you!

Comment: I have made more research about this problem, please move to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135987/why-xgboost-cv-and-sklearn-cross-val-score-give-different-results

Answer (score 0):

You pass different parameters to the both:

- max_depth: 5 vs 2
- eta: 0.1 vs 0.3 (default)
- min_child_weight: 2 vs 4

The parameters you pass to sklearn are more conservative (it's less likely you will overfit the model), so the algorithm does not try too much to fit the model to the data. In turn, on second you get a lower score - exactly what should be expected.

Comment: As far as I know, the parameters specified in `param` will override those specified in `XGBClassifier`, and `learning_rate` in `XGBClassifier` is exactly `eta` in XGBoost, so I guess I'm passing the same parameters to them.