# Why xgboost.cv and sklearn.cross_val_score give different results?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

I'm trying to make a classifier on a data set. I first used XGBoost:

```
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv("train_users_processed_onehot.csv")
labels = train["Buy"].map({"Y":1, "N":0})

features = train.drop("Buy", axis=1)
data_dmat = xgb.DMatrix(data=features, label=labels)

params={"max_depth":5, "min_child_weight":2, "eta": 0.1, "subsamples":0.9, "colsample_bytree":0.8, "objective" : "binary:logistic", "eval_metric": "logloss"}
rounds = 180

result = xgb.cv(params=params, dtrain=data_dmat, num_boost_round=rounds, early_stopping_rounds=50, as_pandas=True, seed=23333)
print result
```

And the result is:

```
        test-logloss-mean  test-logloss-std  train-logloss-mean  
0             0.683539          0.000141            0.683407
179           0.622302          0.001504            0.606452
```

We can see it is around 0.622;

But when I switch to `sklearn` using the exactly same parameters(I think), the result is quite different. Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
import pandas as pd

train_dataframe = pd.read_csv("train_users_processed_onehot.csv")
train_labels = train_dataframe["Buy"].map({"Y":1, "N":0})
train_features = train_dataframe.drop("Buy", axis=1)

estimator = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=190, max_depth=5, min_child_weight=2, objective="binary:logistic", subsample=0.9, colsample_bytree=0.8, seed=23333)
print cross_val_score(estimator, X=train_features, y=train_labels, scoring="neg_log_loss")
```

and the result is:`[-4.11429976 -2.08675843 -3.27346662]`, after reversing it is still far from 0.622.

I tossed a break point into `cross_val_score`, and saw that the classifier is making crazy predictions by trying to predict every tuple in the test set to be negative with about 0.99 probability.

I'm wondering where have I gone wrong. Could someone help me?

Comment: I think that in the definition of the params there is an error.. it should be subsample and not subsamples.... this does not fix the issue, but you are not setting subsample = 0.9 in that way

Comment: The answer seems to solve your issue, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 21):

This question is a bit old, but I ran into the problem today and figured out why the results given by `xgboost.cv` and `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score` are quite different.

**By default cross_val_score use `KFold` or `StratifiedKFold` whose shuffle argument is False so the folds are not pulled randomly from the data.**

So if you do this, then you should get the same results:

```
cross_val_score(estimator, X=train_features, y=train_labels, scoring="neg_log_loss",
    cv = StratifiedKFold(shuffle=True, random_state=23333))
```

Keep the `random state` in `StratifiedKfold` and `seed` in `xgboost.cv` same to get exactly reproducible results.

Comment: I had this issue too and this solved it! Should be written somewhere on the various xgboost guides as I haven't found one that mentions it!